# What enables a function trait type to be used where an fn type is expected?

Tags: rust, closures

What enables a function trait type (`std::ops::Fn`) to be used where an fn type (e.g. closure, function definition, `fn` pointer type) is expected?

```rs
fn take_closure<F: Fn(u32) -> u32>(_f: F) {}

fn id(x: u32) -> u32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    take_closure(id);
}
```

Is it:

- an impl of `Fn` for each corresponding `fn` type?
- or a coercion, like [the the one from `Fn` to `fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#call-traits-and-coercions)

I'm asking more about mental model than about concrete implementation.

#### Edit

updated the example, previously the example showed conversion the other way. Sorry about that. I created a separate question to ask about conversion the other way: [What enables a closure type to be used where a function pointer type to be used in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549985/what-enables-a-closure-type-to-be-used-where-a-function-pointer-type-to-be-used)

Comment: Note that there is no coercion from `Fn` (the trait) to `fn` (the function pointer). However there _is_ a coercion between the namaless function type (its identity?) to the `fn` function pointer.

Comment: Aren't types implementing `Fn` automagically coerced, so long as they don't capture variables from the environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the former (the implementations are produced by the compiler). From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.fn.html#traits).

> all safe function pointers implement `Fn`, `FnMut`, and `FnOnce`. This works because these traits are specially known to the compiler.

I sometimes think of this as `fn` is a `Fn` which does not capture anything from the environment.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you're both right. My example was out of sync with my question. Your answer is accurate for `Fn` to `fn`, @TeymourAldridge's answer is accurate for `fn` to `Fn`, which is what I meant to ask about.